# How can I use grep and regex to match a word with specific length?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm using Linux's terminal and i've got a wordlist which has words like:

```
filers
filing
filler
filter
finance
funky
fun
finally
futuristic
fantasy
fabulous
fill
fine
```

And I want to do a grep and a regex to match the find words with the first two letters "fi" and only show the word if it's 6 characters in total.

I've tried:

```
cat wordlist | grep "^fi"
```

This shows the words beginning with fi.

I've then tried:

```
cat wordlist | grep -e "^fi{6}"
cat wordlist | grep -e "^fi{0..6}"
```

and plenty more, but it's not bring back any results. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
cat wordlist | grep -e "^fi.{4}$"
```

**Your try:**

```
cat wordlist | grep -e "^fi{6}"
```

This means f and i six times, the dot added above means any charater, so it's fi and any character 4 times. I've also put an $ to mark the end of the line.

Comment: No, it means *f* followed by six instances if *i.*

Answer (score 7):

It's `fi` and four more characters:

```
grep '^fi....$'
```

or shorter

```
grep '^fi.\{4\}$'
```

or

```
grep -E '^fi.{4}$'
```

`$` matches at the end of line.

Comment: You forgot a `.` in your last Regex - now it would match `^fiiii$`

Comment: @stuXnet: Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
grep -P "^fi.{4,}"
```

Note that since you already have "fi", you only need at least 4 more characters.

`.` denotes any character, and `{4,}` is to match that character 4 or more times.

If you write `grep -e "^fi{6}"` as you did in your example, you're trying to match strings beginning with `f`, followed by 6 `i`s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I put the comma after the 3, it shows me words with over 6 characters. When I remove the comma it gives me the words i'm looking for.

Comment: @BubbleMonster If you want *exactly* 6, then yes.. you need to remove the comma. Comma denotes a *range*, removing it will yield exact result.